# Geodesics on Sp(2,R)

Tags: lie-groups, geodesics

Given the symplectic group $\mathrm{Sp}(2,\mathbb{R})$, represented as real $2\times 2$ matrices, I would like to compute the geodesic from the identity matrix $1\!\!1$ to the group element
\begin{align}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\omega & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{\omega}
\end{array}\right)\,,
\end{align}
where I define my right-invariant metric on the Lie algebra, such that the following the following basis of the Lie algebra is orthonormal:
\begin{align}
K_1=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right)\,,\quad K_2=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\,,\quad K_3=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\,.
\end{align}
I believe that the geodesic should be given by just
\begin{align}
\gamma(t)=\exp\left(t\ln{(\omega)}K_1\right)\,,
\end{align}
with $t\in[0,1]$.

Is there a direct way to see from the metric that this is a geodesic? Also, due to the right-invariance of the metric, we should have $3$ Killing vector fields that may help to find the geodesic?

Comment: Why the title does not match the question? the title evokes $\mathrm{Sp}(2N,\mathbf{R})$, in the question $N=1$ which is just $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$.

Comment: @YCor: yes, that's true - I was originally interested in Sp(2N,R), but decided to focus on Sp(2,R) first.

Comment: This is in Helgason, including the fact that there is no such geodesic if $-1\ne\omega<0$: problems [II.A.5](https://books.google.com/books?id=a9KFAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA148) and [II.B.1](https://books.google.com/books?id=a9KFAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA149), with solutions at the end of the book.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler: This is helpful. However, in Helgason they use a pseudo-Riemannian metric, while I really use a metric where orthonormal means positive definite. In particular, my metric is NOT bi-invariant (only right-invariant by construction while left-invariance only holds for a subgroup).

Comment: @LFH You may find my answer and comments about it to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108280/left-invariant-metric-on-rm-sl-n-mathbbr/109951#109951 useful.  The problem you are asking about is not entirely trivial.